# zip four lists to create dictionary with keys from two lists and values from another two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have four lists:

```
list_a = ['hello', 'yes', 'you']
list_a_ind = [0, 1, 2]
list_b = ['he', 'here', 'great'] 
list_b_ind = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create a dictionary with combined index as keys and combined elements as values, result as below:

```
dictionary_ab = {(0,1): ('hello', 'he'), 
                 (1,2): ('yes', 'here'), 
                 (2,3): ('you', 'great)}
```

what's the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet will do the trick:

```py
dict(zip(zip(list_a_ind, list_b_ind), zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict()` directly with `zip()`:

```py
out = dict(zip(zip(list_a_ind, list_b_ind), zip(list_a, list_b)))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{(0, 1): ("hello", "he"), 
 (1, 2): ("yes", "here"), 
 (2, 3): ("you", "great")}
```

Comment: Fun. I'd have just written `{(a, b): (c, d) for a, b, c, d in zip(list_a_ind, list_b_ind, list_a, list_b)}` not thinking of nesting, but your solution is likely the fastest (per the OP's request).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Can you post your solution as an answer? I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Sure, why not? [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73902914/364696).

Comment: I did test. For the OP's specific example inputs, my solution is fastest, but only because it has lower setup overhead; the per-item overhead is lower for your solution, so it wins as the inputs get longer. It's pretty comparable though even at scale though; I don't think it'll matter which you use 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Awesome :) , thank you all so much, did not realize can do nested zip :)

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward approach is a single `zip` unpacked and repacked via a dictcomp:

```
{(a, b): (c, d) for a, b, c, d in zip(list_a_ind, list_b_ind, list_a, list_b)}
```

For your short example inputs, this is the fastest solution (it has the lowest setup overhead), but the nested `zip` solution eventually wins out for large enough inputs (it has lower per-item overhead). This is a *little* easier to read to my mind, being a little more descriptive of what you're doing and how, but not enough to strongly prefer it (it's really fine either way).